# when I use getInstance of itext for image it is redirecting to different location

Tags: java, itext

when below code is used ..

```
String filename="/version2.0/aeviewerplugin/src/aeviewerplugin/views/CGI_Logo_VIGIL.png";

com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(filename);
```

I get the following error:

> C:\version2.0\aeviewerplugin\src\aeviewerplugin\views\CGI_Logo_VIGIL.png
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

please can you give a solution?

Comment: look at >http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386339/4290096.

Comment: actually where is your image ? in _C:\version2.0\aeviewerplugin\src\aeviewerplugin\views_ ?

Comment: I closed the question because Rashmi should learn the difference between a *relative path* and an *absolute path*. That is explained in the answer to the duplicate question. Note that this isn't an iText question. It's about defining the path to a file.